# paypal express checkout checkout button on review information page

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using express checkout. following are the steps.

```
Step 1. it takes me to paypal website to login
Step 2. It displays review information page as attached image.
Step 3. It returns back control to my website to finally contains pay button.
Step 4. At the end it tells successs or failure page.
```

Now i want change here i want to reduce step 3 and i want checkout button on the paypal page instead continue button as shown in attached image.

Any quick idea how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step2: Select first result from Google i.e. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPCustomizing#id0864860D0YK
And found ‘With Express Checkout, you can shorten your checkout flow to let buyers complete their purchases on PayPal. Then, you can skip your confirm-order page.’ Just one parameter needs to be added &useraction=commit